# Break a String after every x sentences

Tags: java, android, regex, replaceall

I have a very long text and I try to break it after every 3 sentences.

**Example**

Source:

`"Sentence 1. Sentence 2? Sentence 3! Sentence 4. Sentence 5. Sentence 6. Sentence 7. Sentence 8. Sentence 9. Sentence 10."`

Should return:

`"Sentence 1. Sentence 2? Sentence 3!
Sentence 4. Sentence 5. Sentence 6.
Sentence 7. Sentence 8. Sentence 9.
Sentence 10."`

At the moment I've the regex `(?<=[\.?!])\s` which matches all the whitespaces between the sentences. So I could use it to split the String and then iterates to add the line break like that:

```
String[] splits = src.split(regex);
StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
int index = 0;
for (String s : splits) {
    if (index == 3) {
        b.append("\n");
        index = 0;
    } else if (index > 0) {
        b.append(" ");
    }

    b.append(s);
    index++;
}
String res = b.toString();
```

But I'd like to do it automatically using:

`src.replaceAll(regex2, "\n");`

Any idea of how I can achieve that?

Comment: You might want to match them using [`"(?s).*?[.?!](?:\\s.*?[.?!]){0,2}"`](https://regex101.com/r/DiCUay/3) pattern

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew looks like perfect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may use the following regex substitution:

```
s = s.replaceAll("(?s)(.*?[.?!](?:\\s.*?[.?!]){0,2})\\s*", "$1\n");
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DiCUay/4)

**Details**

- `(?s)` - a DOTALL modifier (`.` matches line break chars now)
- `(.*?[.?!](?:\s.*?[.?!]){0,2})` - Group 1:

  - `.*?[.?!]` - any 0+ chars, as few as possible, up to the leftmost `.`, `?` or `!` followed with
  - `(?:\s.*?[.?!]){0,2}` - 0 to 2 sequences of

    - `\s` - a whitespace
    - `.*?[.?!]` - any 0+ chars, as few as possible, up to the leftmost `.`, `?` or `!`
- `\s+` - 1 or more whitespaces

The `$1\n` replacement takes the whole match except the last whitespaces, and appends the newline at the end.

Comment: Perfect answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. Works perfectly. But I'm not sure to correctly understand what `(?s)` does?

Comment: @Eselfar  *`(?s)` - a DOTALL modifier (`.` matches line break chars now)*. A dot does not match across lines by  default.